# UITableView Activity Indicator the Apple way

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

My problem is pretty common. I want to show some "loading" stuff while the data that will be shown in a table is being downloaded. But all the solutions I've seen this far is either to add some spinners to cells, or put some semi-transparent view over the app.

What I want to active is the thing that apple does in its apps (for example YouTube). Like, the spinning wheel with word "Loading" is shown on the white background, and then the data is shown.

I have also seen some solution with a grouped style, but my table has a plain style so it isn't helping me a lot I think.

### EDIT

My final code looks like this:

```
- (void)loadImagesData
{
    UIView *tableView = self.view;
    self.view = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367)];
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSArray *images = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:self.place maxResults:MAX_PHOTOS];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.view=tableView;
            self.imagesData = images;
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
```

and imageData setter calls `reloadData` on table view.

Comment: The problem here is that you are setting a pointer to your tableview (also it should be `UITableview *tableview...`) and then changing self.view to another view. This means that now your tableview ivar points to your new view instead of the old one. I hope that this makes it clear...

Comment: @Alladinian I don't get it :(. I looked at it like: i set a pointer to a view so it won't be released by ARC, and then I set a `self.view` back to it. Can you post what should be the correct way, so I'll look at it and understand?

Comment: Ok try this: 
Remove the line: `UIView *tableView = self.view;`
Add the following:
`UIView *theView = self.view; [theView addSubView:[[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367)]];`
Inside your main thread block:
Replace: `self.view=tableView;` with: `[[theView.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];`
So what we did was to add your loading view above the table and once we are ready we remove it to reveal the table. If this doesn't work let me know.

Comment: What is exactly the class LoadingView in your final code? I know this is an old question but now in 2015 can you tell me if this is a good approach? I want to do it this way (save the tableView in a variable, etc)

Comment: hi @sports. This was really long time ago and since then I have not programmed for iOS. But here is a repo with my implementation: https://github.com/Uko/UILoadingView, maybe it will help you to understand what I did

Comment: How do you center the Activity Indicator in the tableview (in a higher layer)? When I drag it to my viewcontroller, the indicator just gets added to the cell prototype. Or is there a more "Apple" place to do this. I dont want to put an indicator in every cell nor do I want to waste precious real estate outside the bounds of my tableview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create a `UIViewController` (not a `UITableViewController` - even if you are about to present a table)
2. Create your "Loading" view and add it as an outlet
3. Create your tableview and add it as an outlet too
4. When the controller is presented set its view property to point to your "Loading" view. When all tasks have completed, switch the view with the tableview

Just don't forget to add protocols and methods involved in order to control your tableview

I hope that this will help you

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Wow, this works cool, just one thing: I've used `UITableViewController` and on the `viewDidLoad` I store `self.view` in a local variable, then set `self.view` to loading view, and lunch thread that downloads data, when it ends loading data, I set `self.view` to that local variable and reload data. There's one problem. Time-to after the data is loaded the _loading view_ flashes, showing my tableview for less then a second and then stays on the screen. Where can be the problem? I thought that `self.view = oldView` should 100% set the view that I'm assigning.

Comment: One thing to watch is that since you are launching a thread to download the data, once you're done you must switch to main thread for any changes in the UI. Also try to set the `self.view` to nil before changing to new view. Let me know if that works for you too :)

Comment: I've added my code to question. When I add `self.view=nil;` before `self.view=tableView;` I get black screen when the data is loaded

Answer (score 2):

Another answer to show an activity indicator inside a UITableViewController, without changing it to a UIViewController.

1. In the storyboard, add an activity indicator inside the table view (but not above the TableViewCell !). It will be inside the table view header (not section header !)
2. Connect the outlet of the activity indicator to your class file

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
   ```
3. Use these functions to show or hide the activity indicator

   ```
   // enable tableview and hide the activity indicator
   func activateScreen() {
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 0)
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView // necessary to really set the frame
   activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
   }

   // disable tableview animate the activity indicator
   func disactivateScreen() {
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = tableView.frame
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView // necessary to really set the frame
   activityIndicator.startAnimating()
   }
   ```

Enjoy !