# Centering Activity Indicator View to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a `UITableViewController` in my Storyboard and then dragged a Activity Indicator View into the controller (along with creating an outlet for it), which I start and stop animating before and after some json content has loaded.

I can see the ajax spinner working fine, but it's displaying visually right beneath my navigator / title area, and when I attempt to center it, it appears centered width wise, appears at the very top near the status area...

I tried the following in an attempt to center it... Here's a quick look at my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.listLoader.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
    UITableView *appDelegate = (UITableView *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:self.listLoader];

    self.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getPosts) object:nil];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Please note that both my `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` are contained within my `getPosts` method and are performed on the main thread. So, to avoid confusion, I can actually see the spinner, it's just all the way into the status area. In fact if I remove the lines...

```
self.listLoader.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
UITableView *appDelegate = (UITableView *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:self.listLoader];
```

The spinner appears, right beneath the navigation bar...

How exactly do I center this??? I figured the method above would work, but obviously it's not working....

Comment: Try setting your centering core in the viewWillAppear. See if it works, I often had trouble with elements loading in a different way i expected them to load.

Comment: Tried that but it appears the same way as if I keep the centering in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that a UITableViewController handles a single tableView, tableViews are special kind of scrollviews that change depending on the contents. Adding stuff to tableviews is very uncommon, which is why you use prototype cells and you change these cells. There is no "unhacky" way to do it.

The proper way to do this is, have a normal ViewController with a tableview, and a view with the indicator. THEN make the viewcontroller conform to the datasource and delegate protocols for handling a tableview.

If you still want to use a tableviewcontroller, this is the so so less hacky method:

[UITableView Activity Indicator the Apple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788199/uitableview-activity-indicator-the-apple-way)

Answer (score 1):

Drop a `UIView` on your `ViewController` sized exactly how you want the `UITableView` to be sized.

Drop the `UITableView` on the `UIView`.  Size it correctly.

Now, drag the `UIActivityIndicator` in.  Make it a subview to the `UIView`, but below `UITableView` in the list of views (so it is drawn over the table).  Now find the x/y that will center it and add these numbers in manually in the settings (on storyboard).

Comment: I've done it in this method before, but this method to me is extremely 'hacky' and I believe there must be a better method for centering the activity indicator within a UITableViewController than doing something of this nature.

Comment: While I agree that it's 'hacky', you may find at some point in time, that you're going to have to do your `UITableView`'s like this anyway for other reasons that Apple should get around to fixing (like extra space in the header sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

The best i have come across:

```
// Center 
CGFloat x = UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame.size.width/2;
CGFloat y = UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame.size.height/2;
// Offset. If tableView has been scrolled
CGFloat yOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
self.activityView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y + yOffset, 0, 0);
```

as defined in following:
[IOS: ActivityIndicator over UITableView... How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363128/ios-activityindicator-over-uitableview-how-to)

The main thing is how to get center of currently visible scroll area and above piece of code gets you exactly that, after that you can easily position your progress view window.

It's simple, no hack solution.